# Streams: toArray crashing after concat

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some code looking like this:

```
Stream a = Streams.from(...).map(...);
Stream b = Streams.from(...);
Stream c = Stream.concat(a, b);
c.toArray();
```

(`Streams.from(Iterable)` creates a stream from an iterable -- seen as `Iterable#stream()` doesn't exist)

The last line crashes with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Accept exceeded fixed size of 266
    at java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.accept(Nodes.java:1224)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:576)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:255)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at ... (my code)
```

266 is actually the size of stream `a`. Stream `b` is 11 elements.

I made a few tests. Removing the `map(...)` from the code makes it work.
The following minimal example also works:

```
Stream x = Stream.of(1, 2).map(w -> w + 1);
Stream y = Stream.of(3, 4);
Stream z = Stream.concat(x, y);
z.toArray();
```

At this point I was highly suspecting my mapping function, however this works just fine:

```
Object[] a = Streams.from(...).map(...).toArray();
Object[] b = Streams.from(...).toArray();
Object[] c = ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);
```

Is there a stream API subtlety that could explain this weird behaviour?

It might be relevant to mention that stream `b` is constructed from a collection which gets filled when the mapping function gets invoked.

Comment: _It might be relevant to mention that stream b is constructed from a collection which gets filled when the mapping function gets invoked._ Please show us. Provide an MCVE.

Comment: What are `Streams.from()` or `Stream.from()` ? Those aren't in the JDK API. Also, does any of your implementation have its own spliterator? If so, can you show it, please?

Comment: *It might be relevant to mention that stream b is constructed from a collection which gets filled when the mapping function gets invoked.* Indeed. The collection underlying stream b isn't populated until the mapping function is invoked, and the mapping function isn't invoked until `c.toArray()` is executed (because streams are laziness-seeking). So one of the stream sources is being modified while the stream is in operation, which violates the non-interference requirement of the streams specification.

Comment: @TagirValeev The close votes are precisely so that OP can update their question without people posting all sorts of assumptions. Note how the close message is not _closed_, but _on hold_. This is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: The mapping function is fairly long. The whole point was to see if there was anything obvious (and in fact, there was, given the information that the collection underlying `b` was modified) *without* me having to conduct a full bissection of the code which would probably have lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your source collection for stream `b` is implemented incorrectly as it uses the default implementation of [`Collection.spliterator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collection.java#Collection.spliterator%28%29) which assumes that `Collection` is not modified during the stream operation (in particular its `size()` does not change). In your case this seems to be wrong.

Without seeing the full code of your collection, it's not so easy to propose a fix. If it's possible in your case, you may perform an initialization when `size()` method is called, so calling the `size()` before traversing the collection would return a correct size (currently it seems to return 0). An alternative would be to override the `spliterator()` method like this:

```
public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(this.iterator(), Spliterator.ORDERED);
}
```

This way the `SIZED` characteristic is not reported and stream pipeline will not rely on the size. Now `toArray()` may work slower as array reallocations might become necessary, but it will work correctly.

Comment: The problem description is correct, the solution is not. Modifying the source collection still violates the contract. There’s no guaranty that the particular collection’s spliterator will invoke the `size()` method to find out its own size. When using `spliteratorUnknownSize` you won’t get an exception regarding the fixed size but may get a `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown by the `Iterator`. Even if you don’t get an exception, it’s not a solution but just a nasty workaround. It may suddenly fail when implementation details change.

Comment: @Holger, the solution is correct under my assumptions (which could be incorrect though). I assume that OP extends `AbstractCollection` or `AbstractList` and when iteration starts, (upon first `iterator()` or `get(n)` call) the collection is fully filled and does not change anymore. Hopefully the OP will provide more details to make guessing unnecessary...

Comment: The OP clearly says that the mapping function manipulates the source collection of the second stream. When that function is evaluated, `iterator()` *has* been called already as the default implementation of `stream()` will call `spliterator()` immediately and that happens before calling `Stream.concat(…)`.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the cause. I'll use my third code snippet as a workaround. My collection does use the default implementation of `stream()` so your proposed workaround should work as well.